# Designing a USB Selector Switch for a Printer and 2 PCs

Tags: usb, switches, circuit-design

I would like to build a circuit that allows me to use a single printer with both of my PCs. It is exactly something like this:

[image: example]

Also, I would like to use this type of switch:

[image: switch]

in order to select either PC0 or PC1.

What I currently have is:

[image: currently]

Now I am stuck because I don't know how to wire up the rest of the circuit so that this single button switches the D+ and D- connections between the PC0 and PC1. Unfortunately, I don't have any MOSFETs at the moment. Maybe a DPDT switch is the only way to go then?

Comment: Usually you would either buy such a box or use a mux chip that can pass high speed USB signals. Why are you so sure that you can connect 5V supplies together, or that high speed USB signals can be switched with a DPDT switch?

Comment: You can not do what you are trying to do with a switch like that .... Not without a bunch of digital hardware in the background ... You can not just flip wires quite so easy

Comment: Agreed with @Justme. Using a mux is probably the best thing you want to use here. Advisable if you isolate your 5v lines however. I think using a mechanical switch will create some weird and unnecessary inductance noise.

Comment: Oh, I am pretty new to electronics (as you can see by my rep) and I thought that using the diodes, the 5V lines could be connected together. I thought that a DPDT switch could be useful after watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-ySUHcP6Tw&t=89s

Comment: Maybe I could accomplish what I want using Arduino?

Comment: @Sheim no. You need a digital multiplexer, because you're trying to digitally multiplex. Exactly as the three comments you've gotten already told you!

Comment: All right, I see. Thank you all for the replies - I will try to get hold of a multiplexer then!

Comment: Remember that USB is serial data and muxes are meant to relay particular serial information depending on the select bits. Arduino would be too involving and cost time and money to utilize. Plus, it might require you to strip your USB wires which is something you really don’t want to do.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind @KingDuken! Thanks

Comment: So... the much easier thing to do would be if your computers are on the same network, hook it to one and share the printer... Or get a Raspberry Pi and use it as a print-server. $35/done.

Comment: Even if you’re not an engineer or some electronics guru, it’s very human to plan out what to do. Always ask yourself why something will or will not work. Find ways to do research. Everything you do or say in life will always require solid evidence. For instance, why do you believe an  Arduino will work? If your answer is, “Well it’s just easy to code.” That may be true but also think about the wiring and things you have to purchase. With our advice on using a mux, now you have to understand how you can configure it, design it properly to meet specs, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Of course, @KingDuken, you are right. I should've better explained the ideas I brought up. What I thought when I mentioned Arduino was to kind of forward the signal on one pin to the other using something like ```digitalWrite(outPin, digitalRead(inPin))``` and, obviously, add the logic to set the ```outPin``` appropriately. But, as I suppose, it would not be efficient enough and cause a lot of errors?

Comment: Sorry to shoot your Arduino idea down, but it would not work at all, or it could even damage things, so don't even try it. I do understand that is an idea that comes up in mind when you are an enthusiastic newbie and I encourage you to continue electrical engineering stuff,  but once you know even basics how USB works, and what Arduino can do, you soon get some intuition what would work and what would not.

Comment: Sure, I will persist in gaining experience and knowledge! Thank you for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch shown in the original post is made for a reason. It likely either has a special analog switch and digital electronics, or a special ["sharing" hub](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB2524) made of millions of transistors.  Mechanical switch of this kind is totally inadequate for transmitting USB signals. At most this kind of mechanical switch can handle LS mouse and keyboard, but not a modern printer, which typically uses 480 MBps HS mode.